# Error con función reduce cuando el array esta vacio en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo una función en javascript que me suma los valores de un array con la función reduce pero en el navegador me especifica que tengo un error cuando el array esta vació , investigando entiendo que cuando esta vació no se debe aplicar reduce, pero lo que no se es como verificar que no este vació el array

Este es el error que me da en el navegador de chrome

> Uncaught TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value
> at Array.reduce ()
> at sumarTotalPrecios (ventas.js:709)
> at HTMLDocument. (ventas.js:489)
> at j (jquery.min.js:2)
> at k (jquery.min.js:2)
> este es mi codigo donde me arroja el error

```
    function sumarTotalPrecios(){

    var precioItem = $(".TotalPrecioProducto");
    var arraySumaPrecio = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < precioItem.length; i++){

        arraySumaPrecio.push(Number($(precioItem[i]).val()));


    }

    function sumaArrayPrecios(total, numero){

        return total + numero;


    }

    var sumarTotalPrecios = arraySumaPrecio.reduce(sumaArrayPrecios);

    $("#nuevoTotalVenta").val(sumarTotalPrecios);
    $("#totalVenta").val(sumarTotalPrecios);
    $("#nuevoTotalVenta").attr("total", sumarTotalPrecios);


}
```

gracias a la comunidad

Comment: Simplemente usa un condicional para verificar si el length del vector es mayor a 0 y a partir de ahi construyes lo demás

Comment: Saludos. Si el escenario que estas probando `arraySumaPrecio` si tiene datos al momento de llegar a `var sumarTotalPrecios = arraySumaPrecio.reduce(sumaArrayPrecios);` lo que debe estar pasando es que tu ciclo `for` no ha concluido cuando ya esta intentando realizar la sumatoria. Recuerda que JavaScript es asíncrono. Asi mismo como ya menciono @BetaM verifica el array tenga datos de lo contrario devuelve 0 (cero).

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de evitarte el if es inicializando el valor del acumulador del reduce en 0, con esto no tendrás problemas si el arreglo es vacío

```js
    function arraySum(array) {
     return array.reduce((total, number) => total + number, 0);
    }
    
    const numbers = [1, 1, 1];
    
    const sum = arraySum(numbers);
    const sumEmpty = arraySum([]);

    console.log(sum);
    console.log(sumEmpty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Colocando la condición de if que precioItem.length sea mayor de 0 se quito el error en el navegador les dejo el código del final

```
 function sumarTotalPrecios(){

    var precioItem = $(".TotalPrecioProducto");
    var arraySumaPrecio = [];

    if(precioItem.length > 0){ 

    for (var i = 0; i < precioItem.length; i++){

        arraySumaPrecio.push(Number($(precioItem[i]).val()));


    }

    function sumaArrayPrecios(total, numero){

        return total + numero;


    }

    var sumarTotalPrecios = arraySumaPrecio.reduce(sumaArrayPrecios);

    }/*cierre de if*/

    $("#nuevoTotalVenta").val(sumarTotalPrecios);
    $("#totalVenta").val(sumarTotalPrecios);
    $("#nuevoTotalVenta").attr("total", sumarTotalPrecios);


}
```

Comment: Saludos. Me parece que colocando donde sugieres el cierre del `IF` la variable `sumarTotalPrecios` queda local al `IF` y en las siguientes líneas reportara como `undefined`.